# Regular $n$-gon in the plane with vertices on integers?

Tags: geometry, analysis, elementary-number-theory

For which $n \geq 3$ is it possible to draw a regular $n$-gon in the plane ($\mathbb{R}^2$) such that all vertices have integer coordinates? I figured out that $n=3$ is not possible. Is $n=4$ the only possibility?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is impossible for $n=3$ as you mentioned, and for all $n > 4$, but the result is nontrivial.

See [here](http://hrcak.srce.hr/file/2836).

Citation: Klobučar, D. (1998). On nonexistence of an integer regular polygon. *Mathematical Communications*, 3(1), 143-146.

**Edit:** In response to the comment, this is possible for polyhedra in $\mathbb{Z}^3$. An example of an octahedron with integer coordinates can be found in the third slide [here](http://ejionascu.ro/talks/troy2011.pdf). If you are curious about general higher dimension characterizations, though, I suggest you post a separate question.

Comment: In higher dimensions then ?

Comment: @AbdulhKhazzakGustavElFakiri See the edit!

Answer (score 3):

For $n>6$ it's easy. Fix $n>6$, pick the smallest regular n-gon with integer coordinates. Move the edges without rotating so that they form a star in (0,0). The endpoints now are on integer coordinates and form a regular n-gon which is smaller than the smallest. That's impossible, so no such thing exists.  For 5 and 6 you need an additional argument with mirroring etc, not too difficult.

Answer (score 2):

We could think of this like placing vertices on lattice and creating regular polygons.

And for $\mathbb{R^2}$ the only regular $n$-gon with all vertices having integer coordinates is the square. And if the polygon isn't regular, then every $2n$-gon will do the job.

The proof is a little bit longer, but it's nicely explained [here](http://paulscottinfo.ipage.com/lattice-points/5regular.html#anchor2) and I think you'd be interested in this.